# Дополнение столбцов в БД из другого хендлера

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Как добавить в последующие столбцы БД данные без повторного подключения к БД? В случае данного кода выдает ошибку TypeError: birth() missing 1 required positional argument: 'birthday'.

```
async def create_user(user_id: int, phone: str, first_name: int, last_name: int, username: int):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('bigben.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO krasusers (user_id, telefone, first_name, last_name, username) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
                   (user_id,
                    phone,
                    first_name,
                    last_name,
                    username))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


@dp.message_handler(content_types=["contact"])
async def contact_handler(message: types.Message):
    contact = message.contact
    await create_user(message.from_user.id, contact.phone_number, 
                      message.from_user.first_name,
                      message.from_user.last_name, message.from_user.username)
    kbrm = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    kbrm1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Ввести день рождения', callback_data='berth'), 
            ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    kbrm.add(kbrm1)
    username = message.from_user.first_name
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Хорошо, я буду обращаться к вам ' + username +
                                            ' давайте _введем_ _дату_ _рождения_. Так я буду знать когда поздравить вас'
                                            ' с праздником.', reply_markup=kbrm, parse_mode='Markdown')


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda a: True)
async def birth(a, birthday: iter):
    if a.data == 'berth':
        await bot.send_message(a.query.from_user.id, 'Введите свой день рождения')
        if int(a.message.text) < 1 or int(a.message.text) > 31:
            await bot.send_message(a.message.chat.id, 'В месяце максимум 31 день, введите день ещё раз.')
        else:
            conn = sqlite3.connect('bigben.db')
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(
                'INSERT INTO krasusers (birthday) VALUES (?)',
                (birthday))
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
```

Comment: В вашей функции `birth` есть параметр `birthday: iter`, который волшебным способом в нее не попадет :) Значение дня рождения берите или из клавиатуры (показать кнопки от 1 до N), или из сообщения пользователя

Comment: @gil9red сделал как вы сказали, но в бд записываться не хочет и выдает ошибку NOT NULL constraint failed: krasusers.birthday, хотя у этого столбца стоит возможное значение NULL

Comment: А что вы сделали?

Comment: @gil9red попытался взять значение из сообщения пользователя birthday = a.message.text

Comment: У callback нет `message.text`, у них значения в `data` находится